# Docker with WSL2 - can't connect to Docker host on Ubuntu VM

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu, docker-compose, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm setting the environment up for contribution to open-source project and got a problem with connection between WSL Ubuntu and my Docker host.
Despite turning exposing localhost:2375 and WSL integration on can't connect - got
`Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at tcp://localhost:2375. Is the docker daemon running?`

Linux kernel patch for Windows installed too.

Comment: do `netstat -an | find /i "listening` can you see anything listening on port 2375? how did you install docker? installation on WSL is a bit tricky, did you follow the original guide in docker's doc? https://docs.docker.com/desktop/windows/wsl/

Comment: Yes, theres is localhost listening on 2375:
`TCP    127.0.0.1:2375         0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING`
But still when I'm using `docker -H localhost:2375 images` on WSL, got `Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at tcp://localhost:2375. Is the docker daemon running?`